# Do "addObserver:" and "didChangeValueForKey:" serve the same purpose?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing

I'm a bit confused about KVO in Objective-C. If my property is KVO-compliant, do I have two choices to emit the notification: 1. `addObserver:.../observeValueForKeyPath:...`and 2.`did/willChangeValueForKey...`, or should we use the methods `did/willChangeValueForKey` in a particular context?

I noticed that the second one (`did...`) can be used to group a number of changes into a single notification; are there other important things to understand about those two ways? Is the first method (`addObserver:...`) impossible to use in some contexts (although the context would be KVO-compliant)?

edit: 
in a subclass of NSManagedObject, only  `did/willChangeValueForKey...` were used, but not `addObserver:.../observeValueForKeyPath:...` : do you know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those two pairs are used by the two sides to the KVO interaction; they are not at all interchangeable.

`addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` and `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` are used by the *client*, the one who wants to do the observing.

`observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` is essentially a callback; it will be sent by the internal KVO mechanisms when the observ*ed* ("provider") object uses the other set of methods (the various `did`/`will` `changeValueFor...`). The notification is actually made at that time, by the `change` methods.

Comment: thanks Iulius Cæsar, i edited my question above, i found an example in Core Data where we don't use `addObserver...` but only `did/willChangeValueForKey...`

Comment: Because the subclass is _being observed_, not observ<em>ing<\em>.

Comment: alright thanks, and where is this `addObserver...` located (in my example with Core Data)?

Comment: It's not in that class; it's in whatever other code needs to be notified of changes. Any object at all (and any number of objects), that has a pointer to an instance of that class, can be added as an observer.

Comment: thanks, ok, i guess the `addObserver...` is in the source code of Core Data, but i could not say where, i migrated from version 1 to 2, and we set a date of birth in the subclass of NSManagedObject, (with these methods `will/did...`) to emit a notification when we set a new date, but which object is listening to it (this is a general example, my example is a simple core data example with a subclass of NSManagedObject)?... just in case you've got the answer, thanks anyway